# How to change peak height in Excel

Tags: normal-distribution, excel

I have a normal distributed bell curve (created in excel). I want to change the data so that the peak of the curve is reduced and the edges of the curve are increased, without changing the overall area under the curve.

I am not sure about the technical terms to be used here, but I just want to shift the data to reduce the peak by 5% in the bell curve.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "shift the data"? You said you had a *curve*, not a set of observations. Please clarify the situation. What does "increase the edges" mean, specifically?

Comment: Please also clarify why you're trying to do this. I expect better advice might be possible if it was clear *why* you're asking about this. Why do you need to shift the peak down by 5%?

Comment: I have created data in excel with the function NormDist(). Based on this data I draw a xy scatter graph which shows a bell curve. By shifting the data I meant to say that I want to modify the data such that the graph representing the new data is 5% lower in height and at the edges of the bell curve they are not close to the x-axis, rather they are a bit higher.

Comment: The purpose of doing it is to get random data and run an experiment on it. The normal distribution data gives result which we need to compare with the results of experiment with the data that forms 5% flatter bell curve.

Comment: what does 5% "flatter" actually consist of?

Comment: @Glen_b I am not sure how to answer your question. But let me explain the experiment, that may make it easy to understand. I am looking for say 1000 people to arrive at a destination in a given time interval. I generate random data (normal distribution), which forms the bell curve. In this bell curve on the edges there are very less people and in the middle very high number of people. Now I want to reduce 5% of the people from the peak and put them at the edges. Which means those 5% people are now arriving either very early or very late. I want to generate data (and curve) with this property.

Comment: For cases where you have *data*, rather than a density curve: 1. subtract the mean. 2. multiply by 1.0526. 3. add the original mean back. However, if you want to generate values restricted to be inside an interval, you should not use a normal distribution, since the normal distribution is not restricted in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*I find myself in a conundrum. I expect this doesn't answer your question, but to express all the ways your question is unclear would take several more comments than the two there now. As such I think it's best to give an answer that superficially seems to respond to your conditions, and explain some of the things you'll need to clarify if it isn't what you want.*]

If you really have a normal density ("*normally distributed bell curve*") for some given population mean $\mu$ and population standard deviation $\sigma$, then you can reduce the height of the peak to 95% of what it was if you increase the standard deviation by a multiple of $1/(1-0.05)\approx 1.0526$ that is, increase $\sigma$ by $5.26\%$. Assuming "increase the edges" means "make the pdf in the tail thicker", this will also achieve that.

The area will still be 1.

[image]

So if I've correctly understood the question, that does satisfy the conditions. [If you want to do it to a *sample*, subtract the mean, multiply by 1.0526, then add the mean back -- you do that to avoid shifting the mean when you multiply]

However, that won't change the kurtosis. If you really do want to change the kurtosis (presumably, standardized fourth moment kurtosis), you probably want to hold the variance constant, but you'll also need to be more explicit about what kinds of transformation you're seeking.

Comment: I am not good in statistics. Just found that the peak of the bell curve is called Kurtosis therefore I used this term. I have generated random data with the help available on another forum discussion. [link](http://www.excelforum.com/attachments/excel-charting-and-pivots/376199d1423517590-a-graph-showing-normal-distribution-over-time-variable-normal-distribution-curve.xlsx). I will try to do what you have suggested. By transformation, I meant that if I multiply the normal distributed data with 1.05 or something like that (I tried it but it does not give the required result).

Comment: The peak of the curve is not called kurtosis. If you mean that the degree to which the curve is peaked is called kurtosis, that's closer to being right (and something you might even find stated in a book), but it's still not correct - at least for the usual moment-based measure of kurtosis. I'll demonstrate that multiplying by 1.0526 *really does* lower the peak by 5% in my answer. [Oddly, your link wouldn't show me anything unless I sign up. I'm not likely to do that.]

Comment: If you take subtract the mean, multiply by 1.0526 and then add the mean you subtracted back on, can you explain in what way it differs from what you want? That might make it easier to give a better answer.

Comment: I have mistakenly copied the link for the excel file, the link for discussion is [link](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/1065488-a-graph-showing-normal-distribution-over-time-variable.html).

Comment: I have tried to incorporate your suggestion in generating the data. The problem is when I put 0.05 (5% change) the total results 9997.89 instead of 10000. If I increase the %change the difference increases. This means that the area under the curve (total) is not the same as the normal distribution.

Comment: The problem would likely be (as I already just said) because normal distributions aren't actually restricted to an interval. If you want to have results restricted to an interval, you have to properly deal with the fact that you're cutting the tails off the normal... (or change to use a distribution that is actually restricted to the required interval). If you want advice on simulating from truncated normals, there's already some questions here on that.

Comment: I understand it now. I will have a look at what you have suggested. Thanks for giving an answer and clarifying it for me.

Comment: The thing with truncated normals is you have to increase (scale up) the probability density to account for what falls outside the ends. [In this case, the amount outside is so small that it's smaller than the roundoff error in the 5.26%, so the advice changes only in so far as it requires an extra scaling step -- or possible a few additional values generated if you're actually generating sample arrival times] ... see the denominator [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution#Definition), which in your example will be a number just a tiny fraction below 1.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a symmetric beta distribution (which for large values of the parameter will look very normal), and play with the parameter (reducing it will make the distribution both more spread and less peaked) -- but the whole distribution stays inside the required limits. At $\alpha=\beta=1$, you get uniform arrivals.